# How to make implementations of traits more generic

Tags: generics, rust, traits

So I have a trait called "Widget" which is quite simple:

```
pub trait Widget<T> {
    fn common(&self) -> &Common;
    fn value(&self) -> &T;
    fn value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T;
}
```

Other than the custom struct `Common` (defined elsewhere), it should be clear that the Widget trait simply specifies that an immutable or mutable reference can be returned using `.value()` and `.value_mut` functions, **and this will be of the same type as the Widget itself (`T`)**.

So, for example, I have a "NumberWidget", like this...

```
pub struct NumberWidget<T> {
    common: Common,
    value: T,
    range: RangeInclusive<T>,
}

impl<T: Numeric> NumberWidget<T> {
    pub fn new(
     ...etc.
```

...which is constrained by the trait bound `Numeric` - it can only apply to primitive numbers.

I want `NumberWidget` to satisfy the trait `Widget`, of course. But I cannot simply write...

```
 impl Widget for NumberWidget {
```

Because both Widget and NumberWidget need a generic argument.

So let's say I want to have integer and float versions of "NumberWidget". The only way I have so far which works and compiles is to implement both explicitly:

```
impl Widget<f64> for NumberWidget<f64> {
    fn common(&self) -> &Common {
        &self.common
    }
    fn value(&self) -> &f64 {
        &self.value
    }
    fn value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.value
    }
}

impl Widget<i64> for NumberWidget<i64> {
    fn common(&self) -> &Common {
        &self.common
    }
    fn value(&self) -> &i64 {
        &self.value
    }
    fn value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i64 {
        &mut self.value
    }
}
```

**This is fine for just two variations, but it's already more duplication than I feel comfortable with.** I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
impl Widget<T: Numeric> for NumberWidget<T>
```

But this is not valid:

```
trait takes 1 generic argument but 0 generic arguments were supplied
expected 1 generic argument

associated type bounds are unstable
see issue #52662 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662> for more information

associated type bindings are not allowed here
associated type not allowed here

cannot find type `T` in this scope
```

.etc. etc.

Is there a way to construct instances such as `NumberWidget<i64>`, `NumberWidget<usize>`, `NumberWidget<f32>`, etc. without having to implement `impl NumberWidget<i64> for Widget<i64>`, etc. explicitly for every possible Numeric type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've merely placed the type parameter in the wrong place, you're looking for this:

```
impl<T: Numeric> Widget<T> for NumberWidget<T> {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ The type parameter goes on the impl block itself
    fn common(&self) -> &Common {
        &self.common
    }
    fn value(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }
    fn value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Any idea where this sort of thing is documented nicely? I couldn't find it in the Rust Programming Language Book, for example, although of course I might have missed it.

Comment: It's called a _blanket implementation_ and you can read more about it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods).